# Invalidate Visual Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm building an MVVM application.

I have a view with several subviews:

- MainView

  - SubView1

    - SubView2
    - SubView2
  - SubView1

    - SubView2

      - SubView3
  - SubView1
  - ...

I use several ItemControls to visualize my elements.

I want to display my MainView in a ScrollViewer --->
I use AutoResizeCanvas - my own class to calculate the size of the View. (this class works with MeasureOverride)

Everything works fine so far. (On Initializion)

Now my user can move elements with the mouse - now I would need to remeasure the canvas to actualize my Scrollviewer..

I was trying to do this with an Event of my ViewModel handled in the View.

```
void _Network_UpdateLayout()
{
    MainCanvas.InvalidateVisual();
    MainCanvas.InvalidateMeasure();
    MainCanvas.InvalidateArrange();
}
```

But not every UIElement Invalidate its measure. (Just MainCanvas) - that's why my Scrollviewer Content-Height is not correct.

Please help me!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Are you using absolute sizes? Or is your Canvas relative?

Comment: everything is relative..